# How can I read in a remote image file in Tensorflow for classification?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

I trained a classifier in the [Tensorflow for Poets tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0).

Works great locally, but how can I modify this to use images when I have a URL?

```
   import tensorflow as tf

   # change this as you see fit
   image_path = sys.argv[1]

   # Read in the image_data
   image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()
```

But how can I classify images from an external url? e.g. `http://www.google.com/logo.png`

Answer (score 2):

Figured out we can use urllib.request.

Substitute:

```
   image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()
```

With:

```
   # image_url = "http://www.google.com/logo.png"
   req = urllib.request.Request(image_url)
   response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
   image_data = response.read()
```

Comment: I'm new to python. I'm facing the error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'